# Locking layer from being edited in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, data-driven-pages

I'm using data driven pages to create ~40 page map and I did so by creating a grid. I want to move and delete labels based upon the grid pattern so I do need to see it in data view, but a number of times I've accidentally deleted a grid in addition to the annotations I am editing. All my files are in the same geodatabase so they are all open for editing when I turn on edit mode.

Is there a way that I can just mark my grid as something that cannot be edited?

Comment: Have you tried making the grid layer unselectable?

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/specify-which-layers-can-be-edited.htm